# Vuejs reactive v-if template component

Tags: vue.js

I'm struggling to understand how to make my component reactive. At the moment the button is rendered correctly but once the create/delete event happens, the template does not change. Any tips on how to update the component after the event has taken place?

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});


Vue.component('favourite-button', {
  props: ['id', 'favourites'],
  template: '<input class="hidden" type="input" name="_method" value="{{ id }}" v-model="form.listings_id"></input><button v-if="isFavourite == true" class="favourited" @click="delete(favourite)" :disabled="form.busy"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><button class="not-favourited" v-else @click="create(favourite)" :disabled="form.busy"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><pre>{{ isFavourite == true }}</pre>',

  data: function() {
    return {
        form: new SparkForm({
            listings_id: ''
        }),
    };

  },


  created() {
      this.getFavourites();

  },

  computed: {
      isFavourite: function() {

        for (var i = 0; this.favourites.length; i++)
          {
            if (this.favourites[i].listings_id == this.id) {
            return true;

          }
        }
      },

    },

  methods: {

    getFavourites() {
        this.$http.get('/api/favourites')
          .then(response => {
            this.favourites = response.data;
          });
        },

    create() {
        Spark.post('/api/favourite', this.form)
            .then(favourite => {
            this.favourite.push(favourite);
            this.form.id = '';

            });


        },

        delete(favourite) {
            this.$http.delete('/api/favourite/' + this.id);
            this.form.id = '';

        }
      }

    });

Vue.component('listings',  {
    template: '#listing-template',

    data: function() {
      return {
            listings: [], favourites: [],
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.getListings();
    },

    methods: {
      getListings() {
          this.$http.get('/api/listings')
            .then(response => {
              this.listings = response.data;
          });
        }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue expects HTML template markups to be perfect. Otherwise you will run into multiple issues.

I just inspected your template and found an issue - the first `<button>` element does not close.

Here is the updated version of your code:

```js
Vue.component('favourite-button', {
    props: ['id', 'favourites'],
    template: `
        <input class="hidden" type="input" name="_method" value="{{ id }}" v-model="form.listings_id"></input>
        <button v-if="isFavourite == true" class="favourited" @click="delete(favourite)" :disabled="form.busy">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        </button> <!-- This is missing in your version -->

        <button class="not-favourited" v-else @click="create(favourite)" :disabled="form.busy">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <pre>{{ isFavourite == true }}</pre>
    `,
    ...
```

Note the comment on 7th line above, the closing `</button>` tag is not present in your template.

As a side note, if you do not want to type back-slash at the end of every line to make multi-line template strings, you can use back-ticks as shown in my code example above. This will help you avoid markup errors leading to Vue component issues and many hours of debugging.

Another reference: Check out "Multi-line Strings" in this page: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Relevant lines (copied from above page):

*Any whitespace inside of the backtick syntax will also be considered part of the string.*

```js
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
```

**EDIT: Found a possible bug in code**

Here is another issue in your `create` method of `favourite-button` component:

```js
methods: {
    // ...
    create() {
        Spark.post('/api/favourite', this.form)
            .then(favourite => {
                this.favourite.push(favourite);  // Note: This is the problem area
                this.form.id = '';
            });
    },
    //...
}
```

Your success handler refers to `this.favourite.push(...)`. You do not have `this.favourite` in `data` or `props` of your component. Shouldn't it be `this.favourites`?

Comment: Thanks mani I didn't spot the </button>, I've also adopted your backtick for multi-line templates - super helpful!

Comment: However, this didn't fix the reactivity of the button. I'm still investigating a solution.

Comment: @BenF Can you check my edits in the answer above? There is a potential bug in your `create` method of `favourite-button` component.

Comment: noted and thanks. For some reason both `this.favourite.push(favourite);` and `this.favourites.push(favourite);` work. Is the problem I'm not seeing the button reactive because I'm not calling `isFavourite` dynamically in `data`?

Comment: I am surprised that this.favourite.push works, as it should ideally give error like `cannot invoke push on undefined`. Nevertheless, your `isFavourite` is a computed property, which seems ok to me.  It need not be part of your `data`, as long as you are computing its value correctly. This does not look like a Vue rendering issue, but your application logic needs to be evaluated thoroughly using `console.log` at a lot of places, using pre-defined test data for which you know the output. Most importantly, you need to test the computed property for `isFavourite` if the logic is right.